# Any simple Java way to pass parts of a hashmap to another hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, wrapper

For my trading program, a Merchant object has a qualities HashMap of enumerated Qualities with Boolean values.

```
public class Merchants {
   private Map<Qualities, Boolean> qualities = new HashMap<Qualities, Boolean>();
```

I would like to give each Merchant object a further ratedQualities HashMap of True Qualities with Byte or Integer values representing the Rating of those Qualities.

For example, a given Merchant could have a "1" Rating associated with their True Stockbroking Quality.

The problem is Java does not let me do this easily. The following code demonstrates my intentions but doesn't compile:

```
private Map<qualities-TRUE, Byte> ratedQualities = new HashMap<qualities-TRUE, Byte>();
```

According to this [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058149/using-a-byte-array-as-hashmap-key-java) one solution is to create a Wrapper for the qualities HashMap. Is this the only solution or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you need the mapping to boolean? Can't you replace that with the Map simply not containing an entry for keys which you would have mapped to false?

Comment: @Thomas Lotzer, I use the Boolean mapping to determine which Merchants have multiple qualities. Assuming your suggestion is doable, I will try in future to replace that with a Map containing only entries that are true.

Comment: Following Thomas' comment, if you give up false values, replace the value type to be Integer and then you have both the qualities and their respective rate in a single map.

Comment: @Eyal and Thomas Lotzer, thank you for your suggestions. It makes for simpler code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want, but I suggest you take a look at the Google Collections framework. It has a Maps class that provides several methods to filter your map based on keys, values, or almost anything else. It also contains a Multimap class you can use to easily map more than one value to a key.

Comment: @Thomas Lötzer:  DOn't know about the ops case, but adding true or false allows you to use the case without a value to indicate unknown, i.e. a Boolean, if a boolean was acceptable the op could just use a Set as teh value has become redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an implementation of Merchant using the ideas espoused by Thomas Lötzer and others.

```
class Merchant
{
    Map<Quality, Integer> ratings = new HashMap<Quality, Integer>();

    boolean hasQuality(Quality quality)
    {
        return ratings.containsKey(quality);
    }

    int getRatingOfQuality(Quality quality)
    {
        Integer rating = ratings.get(quality);
        return (rating != null) ? rating : 0;
    }

    void setRatingOfQuality(Quality quality, int rating)
    {
        ratings.put(quality, rating);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have upvoted you, Thomas, Eyal, and Aaron, who all deserve credit for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem I don't see with just looping over the entries of `qualities` and adding it to an empty `ratedQualities` iff the value of the entry in `qualities` equals true?

That'd be my approach if I understood your question right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right that a loop could do this. However I was hoping there was a simple way to initialise this, as I have numerous similar classes to Merchants with numerous similar attributes stored in HashMaps.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to replace the `Boolean` in the map `qualities` with an `Integer` and treat `Boolean.FALSE` as `Integer.valueOf(0)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for suggestion Boolean.FALSE be Integer.valueOf(0).