# Java: can I have arrays in Hashmaps?

Tags: java

Can I have arrays in Hashmaps ?

If so, what's the exact syntax to declare such hashmap ?

thanks

Comment: Are the arrays your keys or your values?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are objects, too. Even primitive arrays like `int[]`.

```
Map<String,String[]> map = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
```

Comment: Uhm, what about this: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>[]> ? I get an error. I have an array with Lists inside.

Comment: I don't get an error from `Map<String, List<String>[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>[]>();`

Comment: @user680406 I think you'll need to clarify what you're trying to do. Are you confusing arrays and ArrayLists? In your example (that you said didn't work) you are creating a Map where each value in the map is an array of Lists of Strings i.e. each String key maps to an array and each element of that array is a List and each element of that List is a String! Is that right? I'm thinking maybe you've gone one step too far and what you want is either HashMap<String, List<String>> or HashMap<String, String[]> - is that right?

Comment: @user680406: I'm guessing you actually want `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>`.  It would be silly to have an array of `ArrayLists`.

Answer (score 2):

Value? that's fine, an array is an Object.

Key? Not so easy - see here:

[Using a byte array as Map key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058149/using-a-byte-array-as-hashmap-key-java)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Below is an example that uses int [] as values. Example [here](http://www.javadb.com/creating-and-storing-arrays-in-a-map).

```
Map<String, int[]> map = new TreeMap<String, int[]>();
```

Comment: what about this: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>[]> ? I get an error. I have an array with Lists inside.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap<String, String[]> ab = new HashMap<String, String[]>();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ArrayList instead of a primitive array. Becouse of the == comparision done inside of the HashMap class.

So, you could have something like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

When the map checks if some element (given its key "k") is present in the array it computes its hashcode. If there's some element at that position "k", then a colision may be produced, so it checks if the elements are the same. Something that can have some troubles with primitives arrays.