# Using a char array as Hashtable key

Tags: java, hashtable

I am working with `Hashtable` in my java program. I just surprised by seeing the abnormal behavior of `Hastable`. Below is my code (This is not my final code, i simply created a new simple project with the code which is running abnormal)

```
    Hashtable<char[], char[]> h1 = new Hashtable<char[], char[]>();
    char[] key = Integer.toString(12).toCharArray();
    char[] val = Integer.toString(21).toCharArray();
    h1.put(key, val);
    System.out.println(h1.containsKey(Integer.toString(12).toCharArray()));// Should print true, since 12 is there in Hashtable
```

Comment: any specific reason u are using a char[] instead of String?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a byte array as HashMap key (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058149/using-a-byte-array-as-hashmap-key-java)

Comment: You can't even use StringBuffer/Builder as Key in Hashmap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790423/string-vs-stringbuffer-as-hashmap-key/23790485#23790485

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use arrays like this as map keys, because arrays have the default, referential-equality-based `Object` implementations of `equals` and `hashCode`.  Using `String` as the key instead would make your program work as desired.

Comment: But I've used arrays of integers. I didn't face any problems.

Comment: @crucified You did, maybe you just didn't notice it.. But since the basic statement ("arrays have referential equality") is true for *any* array, that's just how it is.

Comment: @Voo is right.  `int[] a = {1}; int[] b = {1}; System.out.println(a == b)` prints `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Array equality is based on referential equality ("Are these two references to the same object?") not deep equality ("Are these two objects semantically identical?"). Look:

```
char[] one = Integer.toString(12).toCharArray();
char[] two = Integer.toString(12).toCharArray();
System.out.println(one == two); // false
```

http://ideone.com/YwEjV

Comment: They aren't referring to the same object. In my above code, i used `Integer.toString()`. But in my actual code, i am working with `char[]`. So what can be done now?

Comment: Use `String`s, not `char[]`s, as map keys. Also, you probably should be using `HashMap` instead of the legacy `Hashtable`. ...Also it would improve the code clarity to write `"12".toCharArray()` or `new char[]{'1', '2'}` instead of `Integer.toString(12).toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

if a and b are 2 arrays than a.equals(b) if a == b.  So hashCode of a == hashCode of b if a == b.  Since this is not the case here, it will not be found in the hashtable.  Using arrays as hashtable keys is a bad idea.  Also using any mutable object as a hashtable key is a bad idea.

Comment: Your logic is not _completely_ sound, since (in practice) the `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` method implementations are independent.

Comment: Part of the contract of equals and hashCode is to be consistent between each other.  I would assume that Java follows it's own contract.