# How to use byte arrays as keys in MapDB

Tags: java, mapdb

I have a use case where I'd like to use opaque byte[] as keys into a MapDb. I discovered this - [Using a byte array as Map key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058149/using-a-byte-array-as-hashmap-key-java) - limitation quickly; and wonder which approach is recommended.

I'd rather not create a bunch of interim objects and serialization overhead, but it seems like `ByteBuffer.wrap(my_bytes)` is where Java is pointing me.

I'm hoping one of the core devs of MapDB can weigh in on this or a `ByteBuffer` JVM guru.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MapDB author here.

It is possible to use byte[] without wrappers. There is Hasher which handles hashCode and equals methods for HTreeMap:

```
    Map map = db.createHashMap("map")
            .hasher(Hasher.BYTE_ARRAY)
            .keySerializer(Serializer.BYTE_ARRAY)
            .makeOrGet();
```

Comment: I know this is old, but for future reference: `Hasher` doesn't exist anymore, but I believe the `Serializer.BYTE_ARRAY` will handle this automatically. I'll let Jan correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can't see anything wrong in the approach suggested in the linked answer. They say you have to wrap your byte array into some class having predictable and consistent `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementations. Someone suggests using `String` or `ByteBuffer`, but that would definitely be a hack and may screw up at some point. This simple wrapper may be enough (note that I made a defensive copy of the input bytes to prevent modifications that will alter `hashCode()` and `equals()` computations: key in maps must be immutable):

```java
class HashtableByteArray {

  private final byte[] data;

  public HashtableByteArray(byte[] data) {
    this.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(data);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other instanceof HashtableByteArray
      && Arrays.equals(data, ((HashtableByteArray) other).data);
  }
}
```

This sample relies heavily on the utils in the [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29) class, but you can certainly build your version with optimized hashCode() and equals() that better suite your needs.

Comment: This is a good recommendation in the general case. Having now read the code for `ByteBuffer` this implementation has the lowest overhead of any wrapping solution. `ByteBuffer` tracks a number of fields that are unnecessary for basic consumption.