# Java - containsKey() on HashMap returning null - is it checking for the exact object rather than just a matching key?

Tags: java, hashmap, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, containskey

I've got a HashMap of Integer[], Integer[]. One of the entries is:

> WEIGHTS.put(new Integer[]{0,0,0,0,0}, new Integer[]{20,20,15,15,10,10,5,5});

I then call:

> probabilities = WEIGHTS.get(sheriffAndBanditPositions);

where sheriffAndBanditPositions is:

> Integer[] sheriffAndBanditPositions = new Integer[]{0,0,0,0,0};

This results in probabilities being null. Why is this? How can I check if a matching Integer[] key is in the HashMap if the above isn't possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array doesn't work as key in `HashMap`, since arrays don't override `Object`'s `hashCode` and `equals` methods. `containsKey` would only return true if you pass the exact same instance you passed to `put`.

You can use a `List` or `Set` as the key instead of an array.

For example :

```
Map<List<Integer>,Integer[]> WEIGHTS = ...
WEIGHTS.put(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0,0,0,0,0}), new Integer[]{20,20,15,15,10,10,5,5});
List<Integer> sheriffAndBanditPositions = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0,0,0,0,0});
probabilities = WEIGHTS.get(sheriffAndBanditPositions);
```

Comment: Guava has some utilities for this, as well.

Comment: Ah damn, thanks for the info!

Comment: @James I added a slight workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938180/hashmap-with-byte-array-key-and-string-value-containskey-function-doesnt-wo). Might be of interest to you.