# Should I use an int[] as a key to a Map in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am wondering why sometimes I am not able correctly populate a HashMap when I initialize it with an int[] as its key. For example:
`Map<int[], Integer> prefixSum = new HashMap<>(); prefixSum.put(new int[]{i, j}, sum);`

When I try to retrieve a value (prefixSum.get(new int[] {0, 0}) it returns null. My confusion is that I have done the same thing before and I've gotten no issues whatsoever.

I had to use a [`List<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) instead and that had no issues working.

Comment: I think the default equality comparer for arrays is to compare references so `new int[] {0, 0}` won't match what's already there

Comment: apokryfos is correct, arrays do not override `equals` or `hashCode`, both of which `HashMap` relies on. So, to answer your question directly: No, you should not use `int[]` (or any array) as a map key. Also, make sure to never mutate a key once it's been put into the map.

Comment: Although the question [Using a byte array as Map key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058149/using-a-byte-array-as-map-key) is about using a byte array as a Map key, you should find  the lessons in the answers there apply to this question.

Comment: By the way, in Java 21+, you could use  [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) which covers `List`and more. See [*Java JEP 431*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).